# Date format issue in C# dataset

Tags: c#

I have a problem related with the date format. Date field having value in database is “NULL”. But when I fetch data using query[C#.net], value is showing like ‘0001-01-01T05:30:00+05:30’ .This happens only in a few machines.

Please find the various results from SQL Server and C# dataset.

**SQL Output [Results obtained when query executed in database]**

```
PART_NO                    END_OF_LIFE 
--------------------------------------
003992611-FN               NULL
```

**Data in Dataset**

```
PART_NO                    END_OF_LIFE 
--------------------------------------
003992611-FN               0001-01-01T05:30:00+05:30
```

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: An uninitialized date is represented as 01/01/0001 in the system. You will need to handle logic to set the date to something else if the date is null from the database. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 5):

It looks like that's really just `DateTime.MinValue`, adjusted to the local time zone. You haven't shown any of the code that you're using to access the data, but I'd expect that if you use a `DateTime?` type in any decent ORM, or us [`DataRow.IsNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea9kk67f.aspx) if you're using plain `DataTables` etc, then you should be able to detect the null values with no problems.

Comment: Hi Jon... Please see my table structure and codes                                                                         //CREATE TABLE DATE_TEMP (PART_NO VARCHAR(40),END_OF_LIFE SMALLDATETIME)

                //INSERT INTO DATE_TEMP VALUES ('003992611-FN',NULL)                                                            SELECT PART_NO,END_OF_LIFE FROM DATE_TEMP

Comment: @user2335667: That's just the SQL. We still have no idea what your C# code looks like. Please edit your question (rather than adding a comment) to make it clearer.